# How to specify a custom salt on Acegi with grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, salt

I have a need to specify a custom salt when encoding passwords with acegi 0.5.2 plugin for grails.

I have found a tutorial that shows how to use a ReflectionSaltSource using a parameter of the user (possibly the username).  However, I was unable to get that to work and I actually need to be able to control the salt more than just picking which property of a user to use.

Specifically, I need the salt to match the format `<hard coded string>_<some user specific property>_<the password>` and then have that string encoded.  This is necessary for compatibility with a legacy system.

Is this possible with acegi and grails?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be in the 0.6 release of the plugin that'll go out later this week.